# convert comparison of vectors in cg to glsl

Tags: glsl, shader

I am having trouble converting a cg shader to glsl.

In cg, there is a line :

```
float4 dst = tex2D(DST, i.uv);
float4 outputColor = (dst > 0.5 ? 1.0 : 2.0);
```

And when I convert it to glsl:

```
vec4 dst = texture2D(DST, v_texCoord);
vec4 outputColor = (dst > 0.5 ? 1.0 : 2.0);
```

I am having the error:

```
'>' : comparison operator only defined for scalars
```

And then I tried :

```
vec4 outputColor = (dst > vec4(0.5) ? 1.0 : 2.0);
```

Still the same error.....

Anybody can give me some advices on how to convert this in glsl ? thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the Cg comparison code is essentially broadcasting each of those operations to the 4 components of the vector, GLSL doesn't have a simple, built-in way to handle it. But it does have *a way* to do it.

Modern GLSL (ie: versions where `texture2D` have long since been discarded) have access to component-wise comparison functions that have the effect of your condition. They produce boolean vectors that say whether the corresponding components satisfy the condition.

You can then use the `mix` function to do component-wise selection. However, you have to manually do the broadcasting of the integers to make this work.

So the equivalent GLSL code would be:

```
mix(vec4(2.0), vec4(1.0), greaterThan(dst, vec4(0.5)));
```

Yes, the order of the values in `mix` is "backwards": the value taken for a false condition (not greater than) is the first one; the true condition is the second.